# C++: use of Lambda function inside the accumulate method from <numeric>

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a bi-dimensional `vector< vector<int> >`, say

`contests = [[5, 1], [2, 1], [1, 1], [8, 1], [10, 0], [5, 0]]`

I want to use `accumulate` to get the sum of the first elements, so I resort to a lambda function in order to access the right dimension in the vector of vectors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > 
        contests = {{5, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {8, 1}, {10, 0}, {5, 0}};
    int sum = std::accumulate(contests.begin(),contests.end(), 0, 
                  [](const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b)->int 
                      {return a[0] + b[0];}
              );
    
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I get as result a long compilation error, the last line of which states:

```
    note: candidate: ‘main(int, std::vector<std::vector<int> >)::<lambda(const std::vector<int>&, const std::vector<int>&)>’
                     [](const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b)->int {return a[0] + b[0];}
                                                       ^~~
main.cpp:37:55: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘std::vector<int>’
```

How can I make the lambda identify the right parameters?

Comment: Prefer to pass `std::vector` by const reference instead of by value to avoid copies.

Comment: isn't the lambda going to create its own copy of any captured parameter anyway?

Comment: Your lambda doesn't capture anything. and anyway, for capture too, you can also choose to capture by value or by reference.

Comment: You are right, only captured variables are cloned, while variables the lambda has already access to (as in my case) can be referenced: "Lambdas can only access specific kinds of identifiers: global identifiers, entities that are known at compile time, and entities with static storage duration. The capture clause is used to give a lambda access to variables available in the surrounding scope that it normally would not have access to. When a lambda definition is executed, for each variable that the lambda captures, a clone of that variable is made (with an identical name) inside the lambda."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble comes from the types of parameters you have in the passed functor. Let's look into the documentation:

> ... a binary operation function object that will be applied. The binary
> operator takes the **current accumulation value** `a` (initialized to init)
> and the **value of the current element** `b` - [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

That's exactly what the error message says: `no known conversion from ‘int’ to ‘std::vector<int>‘`, since `std::accumulate` passes the current accumulation value, an `int`, to a functor that expects a `std::vector<int>` in its first parameter.

So, your functor has to have the following form:

```
// Pass currently accumulated value and the value of the current element
[](int current, const std::vector<int>& b)->int {return current + b[0];}
```

Example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>
    contests = {{5, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {8, 1}, {10, 0}, {5, 0}};

int sum = std::accumulate(contests.begin(), contests.end(), 0, 
          [](int current, const std::vector<int>& b)->int {return current + b[0];});

std::cout << sum << std::endl;
```

Prints:

```
31
```

Comment: didn't see it, what a blind spot

Answer (score 1):

By using `auto`, the type deduction is left to compiler. Then you might have noticed much specific error. So it is preferable to use `auto`

With auto, the below code might have generated much specific error, **subscript requires array or pointer type**

```
 int sum = std::accumulate(contests.begin(), contests.end(), 0,
        [](const auto a, const auto b)->int {return a[0] + b[0]; }
    );
```

and then fixing

```
int sum = std::accumulate(contests.begin(), contests.end(), 0,
        [](const auto a, const auto b)->int {return a + b[0]; }
    );
```